# Readonly property on WCF DataContract suddenly gives exceptions on one client

Tags: wcf, properties, readonly, datacontract

Recently, we've been having a problem with our WCF service. This is how it's set up:

- The service has the necessary ServiceContracts and DataContracts
- In a DataContract, there's a readonly property (see below for code)
- The client uses the same DLL with the Service- and DataContracts (so no WSDL)

This is the readonly property:

```
Dictionary<string, string> _list;

[DataMember]
public IDictionary<string, string> Fields
{
    get
    {
        if (_list == null)
            _list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        return _list;
    }
}
```

The client 'sets' this property easily by using the `Fields.Add()` method.

Now recently we've been getting an exception that Fields should have a setter. I've read this on several other places, but this is the strange thing:

- It worked fine on the client one day, not anymore the other day
- It works fine on other clients, and has been working fine for about 1-2 year(s)

So why this sudden change? Could it be a different .NET Framework (the client may have updated overnight)? Are readonly properties really not supported in WCF, because it seems to work fine on other clients?

Comment: Are you using service reference by any chance? Or you are re-using the data contracts assemblies in the client?

Comment: I recollect having this same problem. Issue was, I believe, client had only .NET 3.0; where the code as written will not work. The serializer was changed after .NET 3.0 SP1 to support read-only properties...

Comment: Generally, passing any complex structures or having logic or behaviour in DTOs are not good. One problem is that if client uses service reference, this behaviour will not be on the client. Funnily, This is a common mistake.

Comment: No service reference, as mentioned in the question but maybe not clear enough, I edited it): The client uses the same DLL with the Service- and DataContracts. I'll check the .Net Framework version, thanks TheNextman.

Comment: You could move the DataMember attribute to the member variable (_list) instead - this technique has worked well for me in the past when I want read only properties.

Comment: For anyone having a similar problem, it could also be code running in Partial Trust (see ook http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186(v=VS.85).aspx). We're waiting for news from our customer to know exactly what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got any news about this anymore, and I'm no longer on that project, so here are some hints at solving this, if you encounter the same problem:

- Code is running in [Partial Trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412186%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) mode
- Wrong version of .NET Framework installed (.NET 3.0 SP1 needed)
- Don't use Service References

Clearly, in my case, the problem was down to one specific client. So the first two options are a possibility.

Comment: I remember having a similar issue like this and the solution was indeed to install .net 3 SP1